# After Effects Circular Image Repeater

Tags: after-effects

Hi I'm trying to create something like this with motion in after effects but I'm unable to find a way to do so. (basically what exists with the shape layer but for images) Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to tell us what kind of motion why want to add. Also, are you asking if things can be duplicated around in a circle? Including a screenshot of what you have now could be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need the plug-in from Red Giant [**Trapcode Echospace**](https://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-echospace/), I don't know if it's enough for your project but for sure it will help you to make most of the work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Necrodeathify, Trapcode Echospace is the best option for this.

However, If you're on a tight budget and cannot afford Trapcode Echospace, **CC Kaleida** will help achieve looks that are similar to your examples. Add the effect to your footage layer and play around with Mirroring, Rotation, Center and Size.

> Effect > Stylize > CC Kaleida

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Without having to use plugins, here's how I would do it.

1. set the anchor point on the layer you want to repeat so that it's in the right spot (using the pan behind tool <kbd>y</kbd>)
2. add this expression to the rotation property (assuming that the comp only contains the kaleidoscope layers. Precomp if you need to): `index/thisComp.numLayers * 360`
3. duplicate the layer as many times as you want.

[image]

If your comp has other layers in it you'll need to adjust the expression. If there are, say three other layers below the kaleidoscope layer you'd use `index/(thisComp.numLayers-3) * 360`, and if there was, say two layers above the kaleidoscope layers and five below you'd use `(index-2)/(thisComp.numLayers-7) * 360`.

You could also **link the anchor points** of the layers with an expression, so that you can adjust the centre of all the layers. This allows for easy animation of the whole effect. Do that by using this expression on the anchor point property of all but the first kaleidoscope layer:

thisComp.layer('name of kaleidoscope layer 1').transform.anchorPoint

Rather than typing this it's easier to use the pick-whip.

[image]

<kbd>alt</kbd>-click on the stop watch to create an expression, then grab the thing that looks like a fire-hose-reel and drag it to the anchor point property of the first kaleidoscope layer. This will fill in the correct path to the property, without you having to type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Spoke script provides a radial layer repeater in After Effects → https://madebyloop.co.uk/products/spoke-radial-layer-repeater-after-effects/